# Haskell class Num not contained in Ord?

Tags: haskell

I was reading [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion) and read that the Num class isn't a subset of Ord. This means that there is a Num type which is not a member of Ord, what could constitute such a type?

> Note: Num is not a subclass of Ord. That means that what constitutes
>   for a number doesn't really have to adhere to an ordering. So that's
>   why we have to specify both the Num and Ord class constraints when
>   doing addition or subtraction and also comparison.

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Complex number](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Data-Complex.html) (Data.Complex.Complex) is one example which is a number (Num) but cannot be ordered (not Ord).

Comment: @semicolon There is no ordering of complex number which is compatible with its multiplication. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492890/ordering-on-complex-numbers.

Comment: @kennytm I mean yeah sure, and likewise there is no ordering of lists which is compatible with half the functions you can do on lists, from `nub` to `reverse` to `concat . group`. Why is it such a big deal if the ordering of a certain number type isn't compatible with multiplication. IMO it is worth it so that you can do things with complex numbers such as make them keys in Maps or put them in Sets and so on.

Comment: @semicolon It's probably a design descision. If you implement your own ordering function, you're aware that it does not adhere to the constraints that the mathematical operator `<` usually follows