# Type Declaration For List of Num

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. The following code generates an error.

```
numOfPos :: Num a => [a] -> Int
numOfPos xs = length [x | x <- xs, x > 0]
```

The code just returns the number of positive elements in the list. The list can contain any type of number.

The error says "Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of '<' from the context (Num a)..."

What is the type declaration supposed to be to allow for this function?

Comment: `(Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`(>)` is defined on the `Ord` typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62-), not the `Num` typeclass, so you need to put both the `Num` and `Ord` constraints on `a` for this to work:

```
numOfPos :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int
numOfPos xs = length [x | x <- xs, x > 0]
```

For more information about why elements of `Num` ("numbers") aren't elements of `Ord` ("objects that have an ordering"), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824671/haskell-class-num-not-contained-in-ord).