# Haskell ordering function

Tags: haskell, typeclass

What's wrong with this?
I tried to write an ordering function defined as this:

```
let orderFunction:: Num b => (a, [b]) -> (a, [b]) -> Ordering; 
orderFunction a1 a2 = if sum $ snd a1 > sum $ snd a2 then GT else LT
```

but I get an error:

```
Could not deduce (Ord b) arising from a use of `>'
    from the context (Num b)
      bound by the type signature for
                 orderFunction :: Num b => (a, [b]) -> (a, [b]) -> Ordering
      at <interactive>:110:21-61
    Possible fix:
      add (Ord b) to the context of
        the type signature for
          orderFunction :: Num b => (a, [b]) -> (a, [b]) -> Ordering
    In the expression: sum (snd a1) > sum (snd a2)
    In the expression: if sum (snd a1) > sum (snd a2) then GT else LT
    In an equation for `orderFunction':
        orderFunction a1 a2
          = if sum (snd a1) > sum (snd a2) then GT else LT
```

Is there a more Haskell oriented way to write the function?

Thanks, 
FB

Comment: read next row of  `Possible fix:` in error message, and read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824671/haskell-class-num-not-contained-in-ord

Comment: Thanks :D I think I got it working.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed by @ymonad, Num typeclass does not imply that ordering feature is supported. So I added another constraint to function definition as follows:

```
let orderFunction::(Ord b, Num b) => (a, [b]) -> (a, [b]) -> Ordering; 
orderFunction a1 a2 = if sum (snd a1) > sum (snd a2) then GT else LT
```

Comment: Note that you will never return `EQ` in that way. You might want to use `orderFunction (_,a1) (_,a2) = compare (sum a1) (sum a2)` instead.

Comment: Oh, this is very elegant. Thanks for pointing me out. I'm pretty new at Haskell :)

Comment: I'd even suggest using the [comparing](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing) function from Data.Ord: `orderFunction = comparing (sum . snd)`

Comment: also, while developing your code, you can just omit the hard-specified type signature at first (if you're not sure about it) and see what is inferred.

Comment: @WillNess That backfires as often as it helps, because when you write your function incorrectly GHC may infer some really bizarre things about it. Better to specify the type you intend when you can, and occasionally try removing the type as a troubleshooting/refinement step, to see if GHC has a better guess than you do.

Comment: @amalloy sure, so the point is, try it *sometimes* without the signature and see if GHCi can help you; don't stand in its way.

Comment: You're right. For an exeperienced Haskell dev it could not make sense  to write type signatures. Actually, I do this just to practice with Haskell type system to enforce my function definition.